# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error when bulk collect same column into its own declared type

Tags: plsql

I have declared a table of type :-

```
    TYPE LIST_OF_MASTER
    IS
    TABLE OF SUBS_INFO.MASTER%type;
    I_MASTERS LIST_OF_MASTER;
```

And I execute this query and get error `ORA-06502` :-

```
    query1 := 'Select master from subs_info where region = ''' || INPUT_REGION || ''';
    EXECUTE immediate (query1) bulk collect INTO I_MASTERS;
```

The column `SUBS_INFO.MASTER` has datatype `varchar2(35 BYTE)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you Need 4 single quotes at the end:

```
query1 := 'Select master from subs_info where region = ''' || INPUT_REGION || '''';
```

Have a look at my example *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c216dd8347474b6b03ff855054b8e512)*